# How can I move the Floor in ZBrush?

Tags: 3d, angles, zbrush

I built a character is ZBrush, added some subtools and extracts and realized I have to move the angle 'cause he is "falling". Is it possible to move him and all subtools around him at once (like groups in photoshop) or change the angle of the "Floor"?

Comment: I haven't used ZBrush in years, but if I understood you well, then this might be what you're looking for: according to [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANl3ECahYoA&list=RDhqipgkk9lHw&index=22), you should be able to use the "Repeat to Other" button to apply the same transformation to all the subtools (you'd use offset + rotate I guess). The tutorial is from 2015, but I think the interface is still the same.

Comment: See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2auzfDnuHQ&list=RDhqipgkk9lHw&index=3) as well.